# French equivalent of the expression "Last but not least" — Un équivalent à l'expression anglaise « Last but not least »

Tags: anglais, expressions

I can't find a good French expression for the English expression : “Last but not least”.

Do you have any suggestions?

---

Je n'arrive pas à trouver une expression française similaire à cette expression anglaise :  « *Last but not least* ».

Auriez-vous des suggestions à me faire ?

Comment: De plus en plus, on utilise « last but not least » en français. Je l'ai souvent entendu. J'attends avec impatience les réponses pour trouver une bonne alternative à cet anglicisme.

Comment: @Oltarus Est-il siii mauvais d'avoir un anglicisme ?  :-)

Comment: @Jez Non, mais selon à qui tu le dis, il risque de ne pas être compris.

Comment: @Jez Dire que *tel* anglicisme particulier est mauvais ne revient pas à refuser *tout* anglicisme. Celui-ci me semble long, peu compréhensible, et sonne mal en français...

Comment: On reprend de plus en plus d'expressions toutes faites en anglais, chaque année la liste s'allonge. Autant essayer de trouver l'expression équivalente, quand elle existe, surtout ici sur ce site.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There is no perfect translation, but there is a similar expression. When you are talking about a set of things, you can say “*le dernier [élément], et non le moindre*” (there are many minor variations). You can find examples, and other translations, on [Linguee](http://www.linguee.com/english-french?query=last+but+not+least&source=english); here are a few examples:

> Certainly last, but not least, we have Gary Wilson.
> ***Le dernier intervenant, mais certainement pas le moindre**, est Gary Wilson.*
>
> The last but not least challenge is the sub-regional security environment.
> ***Le dernier défi et pas le moindre** est lié à la situation sécuritaire dans la sousrégion.*
>
> Last but not least, let us talk about human rights.
> ***Dernier point, mais non des moindres**, penchons-nous sur les questions des droits de l'homme.*
>
> Last but not least is a serious concern which the minister is well aware of but has not corrected.
> ***Finalement, et ce qui n'est pas le moins important**, il y a une grave préoccupation que le ministre connaît très bien.*
>
> Last, but not least, energy means not only hydrocarbons, …
> ***Mais** l'énergie, ce ne sont pas que les hydrocarbures: il y a aussi ...*
>
> Last but not least are the two gentlemen who sit on either side of me here.
> ***Je m'en voudrais de passer sous silence** les deux messieurs assis à mes côtés.*

Comment: C'est ce que j'aurai mis aussi: "Et...Le dernier mais non le moindre." ou "Et...Dernier mais non des moindres".

Answer (score 12):

> Enfin et surtout

To be appended [Gilles' list](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/1794/82).

> Last but not least, I would like to thank Liam and Niamh…
>   ***Enfin et surtout***, je voudrais remercier Liam et Niamh…

Comment: This may well be used in the same way, pragmatically speaking, as *last but not least*, but it doesn't mean the same thing. *Not least* implies only that the last element in the list is on the same level as the others, not necessarily that it is **more** important.

Comment: @BrennanVincent - If the last element actually is on the same level as the others, _last but not least_ would not be expressed. Do you mean that you expect the same litotes in a correct french translation?

Comment: @mouviciel : As a native English speaker, I disagree. I've seen *last but not least* used literally (i.e. meaning *not least*, not necessarily *more*), plenty of times.

Comment: "Enfin est surtout" peut être employé quelques fois, mais l'expression n'a pas un sens équivalent. "Surtout" ne véhicule pas le sens que le dernier cité est un des plus beaux (pas exemple) ou un des plus... (quelque chose). "Dernier est non des moindres" est une bien meilleure traduction, car elle colle vraiment au sens anglais.

Answer (score 11):

Aussi, on entend souvent:

> Et le meilleur pour la fin, ...

Comment: Et [le commentaire de Brennan Vincent](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1793/french-equivalent-of-the-expression-last-but-not-least#comment3764_1795) s'applique encore : pourquoi forcément le meilleur ?

Comment: @NikanaReklawyks - Parce que si ce n'est pas le meilleur, on ne dit pas _last but not least_.

Answer (score 8):

Le dernier mais non le moindre !