# Last but not least

Tags: traduction, anglais, usage, expressions-idiomatiques, anglicismes

Je sais qu'il existe une [discussion pertinente](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1793/french-equivalent-of-the-expression-last-but-not-least-un-%C3%A9quivalent-%C3%A0-lexp) qui est un peu vieille quand même.

1. Peut-on employer « last but not least » en français comme une expression figée ?
2. Linguee donne « enfin et surtout » comme traduction mais je n'arrive pas à la trouver parmi les exemples donnés. Est-ce une traduction qui n'est pas employée souvent, qui est inconnue, ou bien désuète ?
3. Parmi les interprétations apparaissant dans l'autre discussion laquelle est la plus proche de l'expression anglaise ?

Comment: La discussion n’a que sept ans. Les deux réponses les plus votées sont de modérateurs de ce site, encore très actifs ici. **Enfin et surtout** y est donné comme traduction dans [la réponse d’Evpok](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/1795/13100) et la plupart des gens qui répondraient aujourd’hui continueraient d’utiliser le genre d’expressions proposées il y a sept ans.

Comment: @Montée de lait. I don't understand why the question is a duplicate. I have already mentioned the discussion you are talking about. The three questions that I posted here are not answered in the linked question without error of my part.

Comment: Pour le (1), tu veux savoir si on peut utiliser l'expression en anglais ? Pour le (2) : [ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=enfin+et+surtout&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3), que veux-tu savoir de plus ? Pour le (3), c'était l'objet de la question précédente.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Thanks. 1) Yes. 2) Enfin et surtout is given as the sole translation of last but not least by Linguee. Nevertheless, it is not among the examples of usage provided. It appears strange to me. 3) I agree but I cannot figure out a definitive answer (sorry!). Last but not least...I notice an agressive tone in your comment.

Comment: Tu utilises le site comme un forum de discussion. Il y a déjà une question qui traite de cela, il n'y a aucun besoin d'en créer une deuxième.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Je veux éviter les malentendus. Alors dans un tel cas il fallait que je poste mes questions comme commentaires de la discussion originale ? Ou bien éditer la question originale et rajouter mes questions ? Merci.

Comment: Il faut déjà que tu lises les réponses et que tu comprennes qu'il n'y a jamais de traduction parfaite. Ensuite il est possible d'utiliser un bounty (voir lien en bas de la question), si tu juges qu'il est vraiment nécessaire de la mettre à jour. Au besoin, si tu as une *autre* question tu peux la poser séparément, mais le strict minimum c'est d'au moins d'avoir lu l'autre question jusqu'au bout. Et je rappelle que les questions subjectives ou qui incitent des réponses subjectives ne sont pas acceptées sur Stack Exchange.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Ok. J'ai compris.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. *Last but not least* n'a pas vraiment percé dans le lexique français et ne peut donc être utilisé que si son auditoire connait suffisamment l'anglais pour l'apprécier.
2. *Enfin et surtout* n'est ni désuet, ni inconnu. Il y a déjà un exemple d'utilisation dans [une réponse précédente](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/1795/1109).
3. J'aime bien *le meilleur pour la fin* qui est assez courant et apporte une touche d'humour, comme *last but not least*. L'expression est en revanche un peu plus forte que l'anglaise, ne pas être le plus mauvais ne signifiant pas forcément qu'on est le meilleur.

Comment: @jliagre : Merci beaucoup !